# How to solve java.lang.runtimeexception cannot serialize ksoap2

Tags: java, android, soap

In my project I am using ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar for web service purpose.

I got able to access the service and passing simple parameters and get the objects and iterate it.

But the problem is I cant able to send the complex object. Can anybody know how to pass the complex object with date and double values.

Employee object have string name, int number, double salary and Date dateOfBirth.

```
And the employee object implements KvmSerializable
name="Mike"
number=2;
salary=20000
dateOfBirth = new Date();
```

and the code is

```
SOAP_ACTION = "http://xysed/GetHRA";
METHOD_NAME = "GetHRA";

TextView authenticate = new TextView(this);

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("employee");
Employee e = new Employee();
e.setNumber(4);
e.setName("Ananth");
e.setSalary(20000);
e.setDob(new Date());
pi.setValue(e);
pi.setType(Employee.EMPLOYEE_CLASS);
request.addProperty(pi);
request.addProperty("employee", e);


SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
Marshal dateMarshal = new MarshalDate();
dateMarshal.register(envelope);
//envelope.addMapping(Employee.NAMESPACE, "Employee", new Employee().getClass());
try {
AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

//String fullName = (String)envelope.getResponse();
Log.v("Full String :", envelope.getResponse().toString());
Log.v("body in :", envelope.bodyIn.toString());
Log.v("body out :", envelope.bodyOut.toString());

authenticate.setText(envelope.getResponse().toStri ng());
this.setContentView(authenticate);

} catch (IOException ioe) {
ioe.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException xpe) {
xpe.printStackTrace();
}
```

I pass this employee object as a request i got an error like

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oak.soap.test/com.oak.soap.test.WebserviceDisplay}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 20000.0

here 20000.0 is a salary ( double value)

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(287): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 20000.0
```

Can anybody provide samples for how to pass complex object as request to web service

Thanks

Comment: In your web method salary is also double ? I think error occurs because of that line. Maybe in your webmethod salary is int.

Comment: I use float. but in this code I use float it didn't work

Comment: this guy has the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18943475/ksoap2-in-android-cannot-serialize

Hopes, it's useful.